# How to show list of top 10 customers who have purchased most of the products on the site

Tags: product, customer, extensions, development

How to show list of top 10 customers, who have purchased most of the products on the site.

Answer (score 2):

For top 5 customer order collection you can use

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
echo $_collection->getSelect()
    ->columns('COUNT(*) AS cus')
    ->group('customer_id')
    ->order('cus DESC')->limit('5');
```

Row Query

SELECT `main_table`.*, COUNT(*) AS `cus` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` GROUP BY `customer_id` ORDER BY `cus` DESC LIMIT

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've created new file inside `mychildtheme/template/catalog/category/toptencustomer.phtml`

```
<php    
$registerCustomerOrderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('notnull' => true));
    $orderarray = [];
    foreach ($registerCustomerOrderCollection as $order)
        {
                    $order_cust = $order->getCustomerEmail(); 
                    $orderarray[] = $order_cust;
        }
        $ordercounts = array_count_values($orderarray);
        echo "<h2>Top 10 Customers</h2>";
        arsort($ordercounts);
        $count_order = count($ordercounts);

    foreach($ordercounts as $ordercounter=>$x_value)
    {
        $arr = explode('@', $ordercounter);
        $important = $arr[0];
        $imparray[] = $important;
    }

    $output = array_slice($imparray, 0, 10);
        foreach ($output as $cust_name) 
        {
            echo '<h4>'.$cust_name.'</h4>';
        }
?>
```

It gives me top 10 customers, who have purchased most of the products on the site.